# Compare datetime in array of records when iterating through .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a class to the event that is happening now, and am trying to compare the times of each event to the one before and after (if there is an easier way, please let me know)

In the controller:

```
@events = Event.where("user_id = ? AND date >= ?", current_user.id, Date.today.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('Hawaii')).order('date ASC')
```

I'm just trying to get them on the page now, with a .each_with_index, but every event is coming back nil, thus nothing is on the page (let alone, able to compare to the next/previous event)

```
<% @events.each_with_index do |event, i| %>
<h1>Event: <%=  event[i].title rescue nil %></h1>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing here? Also, if there is a better way to go about this, please let me know!

Comment: Could you please explain the "Add a class to the event"? class and event are Models?

Comment: I want to highlight one event in a different color than the others. So I need to compare the events in that array as they loop through, to determine which one is happening now (or next if it's the first event of the morning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event` is a single item, one of the`@events`

So you don't do...

```
<h1>Event: <%=  event[i].title rescue nil %></h1>
```

you do...

```
<h1>Event: <%=  event.title rescue nil %></h1>
```

Or you could do (slightly inelegant)

```
<h1>Event: <%=  @events[i].title rescue nil %></h1>
```

Comment: great explanation!! Thank you very much